# Passing Variables from one functiion to another

Tags: php

I have 4 files. I am trying pass my fetch results through a function to another page. My code is below:

File actions.php

```
  public function getAction($action, $page, Array $vars){

    if(!empty($action)){
        $action = strtolower($action);

        $path = $page.'/'.$action.'.php';

        $currentTemplate = $this->loadActionTemplate($path);

        return Array($currentTemplate, $vars);
    }
    else{
        $action = strtolower($action);

        $path = $page.'/default.php';

        $currentTemplate = $this->loadActionTemplate($path);

        return ($currentTemplate);
    }
}
```

File news.php(controller)

```
$file = VIEWS_PATH.strtolower($this->template) . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)){
    $currentQuery = $newsModel->viewQuery($selectQuery,$returnAll); 
            include_once($file);
        }

    }
```

File news.php(Main view)

```
$factory = new Actions_Factory();


$factory->getAction($action, $page, $currentQuery);
```

File view.php(sub View)

```
print_r($currentQuery);
```

I can't get $currentQuery to print out the mysql dump  on view.php but $currentQuery prints out fine on news.php. I am doing something wrong and can't figure out what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you file probably does not exist (        if (file_exists($file)){
)

Comment: The file does exist as it prints in news.php(Main View) but doesn't print in view.php(sub view)

Answer (score 0):

```
$factory->getAction($action, $page, $currentQuery);

print_r($currentQuery);
```

You set `$currentQuery` to `getAction()`, but this function return result if you want function affect on argument you have to use assign by reference!

Insert `"&"` in `$var` to assign variable by reference

```
public function getAction($action, $page, Array **&$vars**){
```

Comment: getAction calls the page view.php. How do i get the $vars to print on the view.php page. It prints fine on news.php(main view).